# Who would use the word "manky"?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

Both Google ngram and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/it/amp/inglese/manky) tell me that "manky" nowadays used to describe something dirty, as in it's "so old and/or used that it became dirty."

What I am curious about is who you're more likely to hear this word from.

Would a granny who chastises her grandkid to wash his hands use it, or rather a teen describing shabby clothes?

Can we draw any conclusions about the education level and social status of the person using this word?

Comment: I think I've read the word maybe twice, in old fiction.  It's not a word most in the US would know.

Comment: I'm from Yorkshire, UK and this word is common and readily understood. Not for dirty hands, more for clothes or houses that may be mouldy or otherwise filthy. So manky you don't want to touch it without gloves. Or even of badly decayed teeth.

Comment: I'm curious to know where you came across it, if it's unfamiliar?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=manky  British slang apparently

Comment: In the south of England at least it's very commonly used, but is still firmly slang. I hear and use it all the time.

Comment: "Manky" makes perfect sense to a Kiwi as well as a local Australian.  Perhaps its more of an Empire word, and the US left too early to get it ?  Definitely a casual word.

Comment: It's very commonly used in Australia and New Zealand. Often for something or someone which us unkempt (untidy or disheveled). Often for animals (manky dog for an old dog), but quite common for objects (manky fridge, manky bathroom meaning they are quite filthy)

Comment: @DavidWaterworth I assume you're from there? I would like to ask you a question and then delete it. Would that be ok?

Comment: I was hoping that  manky was to hinky as grotty is to gross, but I see that is not the case.

Comment: [Sir Robin the Brave, after he soiled his armour](https://youtu.be/QJC5o7Qt40g).

Comment: @Lambie yes sure

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following extract from BBC blog gives an interesting range of possible regional usages of the term, sometime used also as a verb.

***[Manky](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1453_uptodate3/page12.shtml)***

> It's a regional usage. I've heard it in various parts of the north of England and up in Scotland too. It has a whole range of meanings.
>
> - When you hear somebody say 'my torch is all manky', it means it's not working properly, it's worthless, it's defective, it's a bit inferior. And then, I've heard people say 'oh, he's got manky socks' or 'that baby's nappy is manky' and that means it's grimy or dirty, it might even be a bit smelly - that's another usage of the term - 'bananas are manky' or 'that dustbin is manky' - it means it's rotten, it's disgusting, it's got a smell of some kind.
>
> And it generalises from there, too, into personal feelings - if you're feeling under the weather for instance, in some parts of the country, you can say, you know, 'I feel manky today'.
>
> And then up in Scotland especially, it's used quite nastily, as a term of abuse - you know, somebody might say 'you manky so and so', that's really quite harsh.
>
> [Very unclear origins](https://www.etymonline.com/word/manque#etymonline_v_31698). It certainly goes back to the 1950s, maybe before. Some people think it comes from an old French word meaning 'impaired'. I don't know. Certainly, it's been used in a wide range of constructions now.
>
> - I've heard it used in the phrase 'you're going to mank it up' meaning 'you're going to mess it up'. I've actually heard somebody talk about something being 'mankified'!
>   To mankify - a verb. And then there's that northern dialect use in Yorkshire where somebody says 'I'm feeling manky', 'I'm feeling rough and unwell'. That sort of use so upset people, doctors in particular who didn't understand what it meant, that they actually decided to write a guide to Yorkshire dialect to help them out, and so there you get in this list of medical terms 'manky', feeling rough.

Comment: I'm certainly familiar with it in southern England as well. I don't recall hearing it in Wales but that may say more about the company I keep there

Comment: I didn't know it growing up in Derbyshire in the 60's, nor did I come across in contact with people from the Sheffield area. However when I moved to northern Lincolnshire in the early 70s it was very common. I've seen a suggestion that it's related to the French _manqué_ but the definitions don't match at all.

Answer (score 3):

'Manky' is used throughout Ireland, also. Its use is not a signifier of class or education; the word crosses all social boundaries. It is slang used by anyone to denote bad dirt, not a light soiling.

The definition below from the Cambridge Dictionary is valid in Ireland.

Used to describe an object that is unpleasantly dirty, usually because it is old or has been used a lot:

- a manky tissue
- manky old carpets

Answer (score 2):

***'Manky' in British slang dictionaries***

With regard to the specific question of what social class of people are most likely to use the word *manky*, Tony Thorne, [*Dictionary of Contemporary Slang*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3_6oRAJSHP4C&pg=PA283&dq=%22manky%22+slang&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHpJ6koO34AhXCJ0QIHWPWCkU4ChDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22manky%22%20slang&f=false), fourth edition (2014) has this interesting entry:

> **manky** *adj British* grotty, disgusting, or distasteful. A 1960s vogue word, mainly in middle-class usage. The word had existed previously in working-class  speech: it may be an invention influenced by 'mangy', 'cranky', 'wonky', etc. , or a corruption of the French *manqué* (lacking, failed). It is still used in northern England where its usual sense is naughty or spoilt.

John Ayto, *Oxford Dictionary of Slang* (1998) has two entries for the word:

> **manky, mankey** (1958) British: from obsolete *mank* defective {from Old French *manc*, *manque*, from Latin *mancus* maimed) + *-y*; perhaps influenced by French *manqué* | **B. W. Aldiss** Have you chucked out that dirty manky beer you poisoned me with last time I came in? (1971)

and

> **manky, mankey** (1971) British: from earlier sense, inferior, defective | ***Radio Times***: 'I'm going to have to change my wig, this one's much too manky,' he announces after an extensive session of tonsure teasing. Danny is having a bad hair day. (1996)

Noel Smith, [*The Criminal Alphabet: An A-Z of Prison Slang*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KrDYBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT239&dq=%22manky%22+slang&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie-fLMuu34AhVMK0QIHWZyBtE4HhDoAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22manky%22%20slang&f=false) (2015) asserts that the term has roots in gay slang:

> **MANKY** If someone or something is considered **manky** it means it is or they are dirty or unwashed. The word is believed to be a corruption of the Italian word *mancare*, meaning to be lacking in something (in this case, hygiene). It came into usage via Polari, the secret language of homosexuals, in the 1950s.

Several other special-focus dictionaries and academic works share Smith's view of the Polari origin of *manky*, although none of the ones that I checked provide any early (1950s or early 1960s) recorded instances of the term being used in a specifically gay milieu.

---

***'Manky' in the world of climbing***

In checking early matches for the term in Google Books search results, I noticed several instances involving the pastime of recreational climbing. For example, from Frank Wilkinson, "[Routes to the Top](https://books.google.com/books?id=XqMbAQAAMAAJ&q=%22peg+but+he+couldn%27t+see+the+second+one%22&dq=%22peg+but+he+couldn%27t+see+the+second+one%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWqOf_p-34AhWjIUQIHaKxD3kQ6AF6BAgCEAI)," in *Climber and Rambler* (1963) [combined snippets]:

> Above him was a peg but he couldn't see the second one mentioned in the guide. And then an excited yell told me that he had spotted it tucked away a couple of feet above the first. Some not-too-difficult briding moves and a finger jam got him to the peg. He clipped in and whipped up to the second. A startled cry told me that it was “as **manky** as hell.” But he didn't have time to stop and worry.

From Malcolm Slesser, [*The Andes Are Prickly*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ee1lAAAAMAAJ&q=%22manky%22&dq=%22manky%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiizOXloO34AhXKI0QIHcK8DbE4ChDoAXoECAUQAg) (1966) [combined snippets]:

> We got across some desperate V.S. rock. Still no though of roping up. Right above us this gaping *bergschrund*. We got up on to this **manky** rotten snow, chanked up that for a bit, that was all right. Then suddenly—you know the beautiful ice fluting you get here? We saw this great slope of it and the col beyond Ken went 'Wheeeeeee' and went running at it, and promptly disappeared into the first runnel up to his waist.

From an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=BoU6AQAAIAAJ&q=%22manky%22&dq=%22manky%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_2ePvou34AhUVDkQIHV-ZA2A4FBDoAXoECAgQAg) in *Summit* (1966) [combined snippets]:

> By some crooked means I was appointed leader of the next pitch and by two a.m. after struggling with a small overhang I had gained only thirty feet of "**manky**" A3. With another sixty feet ahead of me, I decided to call it a day and slept in etrier, whilst John and Bill passed the night on stances not much larger.

From an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=hi4tAAAAMAAJ&q=%22manky%22&dq=%22manky%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_2ePvou34AhUVDkQIHV-ZA2A4FBDoAXoECAkQAg) in *Scottish Mountaineering Club Journal* (1967) [snippet view]:

> A 130 feet of rope was run out on the next pitch, climbing over four thin slabs, surmounting three big overlaps, and ending up on a grass ledge with a **manky** peg belay. On the first overlap, a freak sleet shower added to the interest.

And from an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=t2oTAQAAIAAJ&q=%22manky%22&dq=%22manky%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj846nrqO34AhU2K0QIHXd5BXA4PBDoAXoECAgQAg) in *Ascent* (1967) [snippet view]:

> *Huu much? Ah, three pounds, six schillings. Jesus Creest, nuet baad. Ye'ver hung un wunfrum pegs? Nay! Twoud be a **manky** bivvy! Aie, und a cold un at that! Lut's find tu trees ta strung it up un. Aie, und I'll fetch the brew!*

Sure enough, Showell Styles, [*Men and Mountaineering: An Anthology of Writings by Climbers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hdNMAQAAIAAJ&q=%22manky%22+slang&dq=%22manky%22+slang&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju8LLDsO34AhUvBjQIHdgDAbI4MhDoAXoECAkQAg) (1968) includes a glossary entry for it:

> ***Manky***: British climbers' slang for “wobbly” or “insecure”.

And Paul Dickson, [*Slang: The Topical Dictionary of Americanisms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ETw15ZfcSqEC&pg=PT249&dq=%22manky%22+slang&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHpJ6koO34AhXCJ0QIHWPWCkU4ChDoAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22manky%22%20slang&f=false) (1990/2006) indicates that the term entered climbing slang in the United States as well:

> **Manky** (rock climbing). Almost worthless, as in manky protection.

---

***Conclusions***

According to Tony Thorne, the British middle class would use *manky*—at least during its 1960s vogue period, and before that the working class would use it. I doubt that the class lines follow that chronology so neatly. In his song "[Uneasy Sunny Day Hotsy Totsy](https://books.google.com/books?id=NRMoLorcHbEC&pg=PA140&dq=%22manky%22+%22Ian+Dury%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQvYSgtO34AhXFK0QIHaZwDAEQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22manky%22%20%22Ian%20Dury%22&f=false)," written in the period 1978–1980, Ian Dury includes this lyrics:

> Question your besotment with your **manky** job / Squat on your allotment for thirty bob / It's time that the babies were kept quite, shut your gob

Dury comes across as someone far closer to a former working-class street urchin than to a striving middle-class voguer. But there is nor reason to assume that jumping to the vocabulary of the British middle class would necessarily have caused *manky* to drop out of use among members of the British working class. Alternatively

The term also seems to have taken hold, with a somewhat altered meaning among climbers—first in Britain and the throughout the English-speaking world. It also applies with odd specificity to other things in other settings—for example, to lowering skies in the Antarctic region, as we learn from Chris Furse, [*Elephant Island: An Antarctic Expedition*](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=YxUaAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22manky%22+slang&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22manky%22) (1979):

> **MANK, MANKY** Slang for miserable cloud and sleet.

And again from Steve Alten, [*Vostok*](https://books.google.com/books?id=XqXuCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA87&dq=%22manky%22+slang&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjE5_rdt-34AhWhADQIHW5jApM4FBDoAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22manky%22%20slang&f=false) (2016):

> Thirty hours later, True, Ben, and I stood on the frozen waters of Prydz Bay beneath “**manky**” skies. ***Manky*** was Antarctic slang for overcast weather, apparently a common occurrence along the coast.

It also seems very likely that, whether it originated in Polari or was adopted by it from existing British slang or regionalisms, *manky* was in widespread use among members of the gay community in Britain from a fairly early date.